# Execution of volatile instruction

Tags: c, assembly, inline, volatile

```
int __attribute__ ((noinline)) mySystemCall (uint32 Exception, uint32 Parameter)
{ 
   #ifdef PROCESSORX
   __asm__ volatile ("sc")
   #else
   __asm__ __volatile__ ("mov R0, %0; mov R1, %1; svc 0x0 " : : "r" (Exception), "r" (Parameter));

}
```

How does the compiler translate the instruction (asm volatile ("sc"))?

Why are some arguments passed as strings and some are not (ex:

```
 __asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc": "=a" (a), "=d" (d) ))
```

Comment: You may want to look at the examples at [gcc Extended-Asm (and see volatile a few PP down)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)

Answer (score 3):

Inline assembly isn't specified by the C standard. I assume this is code for `gcc` and compatible, then you should have a look at [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).

As for your specific questions:

> How does the compiler translate the instruction (asm volatile ("sc"))?

The `volatile` in this context instructs the compiler that the assembler snippet **must** be included, even if the compiler can't see a reason it's actually needed for the behavior of the program. Whatever comes in the first string parameter is literal assembly code of the target platform.

> Why are some arguments passed as strings and some are not

It's just part of the syntax, refer to the manual I listed above. Inline assembly can "bind" input and output parameters to C variables and also tell the compiler which registers are "clobbered" by the assembly snippet (among other things).

Answer (score 1):

Inline assemblers have to bridge the gap between C and assembly so in addition to ones assembly code, one needs to give details of how they interact. The first item in the GCC assembly template is the actual assembly, the other items include assigning input variables, output variables and clobbers (registers/memory) that the assembly may clobber so C need to steer clear of. The full details may be found: [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).